# What would be the best way to show 3 actions on the bottom half of the page

Tags: usability, gui-design, buttons, mobile-application, actions

We are confused as to which of these UI should we go with to as we have three actions relating to the content on the bottom third of the screen.

Three buttons are:
1. Write to Device
2. Load from saved configurations
3. Save the the current configuration

The first option is have three buttons at the bottom which will be fixed, Here they can come really close to each other and might not explain the functionality

[image: Three buttons at the bottom]

Second option is to have the write/load button on the left and a more button (Both of which will hide on tap/scroll on other part of screen) which will open up an action sheet with three buttons

[image]

Please let us know on which option is better / an alternative.

Comment: What does each of the buttons do? What from the buttons is most often used? Is edit button up right, editing only title or whole entity / device?

Comment: What's the difference between "write" and "save"?  The terminology most commonly used are "open" and "save".  If you have only three options, seems pointless to make users decend into a menu.  However, if number of options will increase, then using a menu makes sense.

Comment: Well, it depends how frequently be used of each button.

Comment: @xiota So we have a hardware device where we "Write" the configuration to the device, "Save" as in save the configuration on the mobile as a file and "Load" as in load a file from the mobile - The problem is the user might have the same doubt as to what each button does and hence we are looking at alternatives where we can explain an action.

Comment: @xul The edit button would be used to edit everything in the black container which is different from the configuration itself.

Comment: @FrankAK The "Write" button will be more frequently used.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you should be consistent, and I dont think repeating twice Write buttom is correct. I would go with "Floating action button" down right, which then toggles menu. You can easily communicate more with icons your actions. "The noun project" is a super source with icons. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too attached to having word labels, you could consider condensing them down into icon-only buttons. This might free up space and make the bottom bar a little less cluttered, but you'll have to make sure the icons make sense by themselves.

(A tooltip on hover/longpress could avoid that confusion, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the configuration screen is too much and require 2 or 3 scrolls to complete scanning all the data then having 3 floating buttons might be a frustrating item for the user.

First, decide the frequency of use of all three buttons. If it is used for too many times that I prefer putting in the centre as one button and later expands when clicked.

If the buttons are very less used then but on the header just beside the EDIT link.

Answer (score 0):

Please Take a look at [this](https://www.figma.com/proto/N7Bex7GoC1NI6djzcJQ2gT8y/Stackoverflow?node-id=1%3A2&viewport=1411%2C1894%2C6.599242210388184&scaling=scale-down) . You can not ask the user to take action by providing three buttons on the same page, instead try with signle button and next provide "Alert" / "Dialogue" / "Pop up Screen". Hope this might help you.

[image: First Scree with single button]
[image: Second Screen to take actions]

Answer (score -1):

If the application prompts to load a file on start, then the additional buttons may not be needed. It would be fine to have a "write" button with the other options in a menu.

To reduce confusion, consider using longer phrases or including hints within the interface to indicate what buttons will do:

- Write to device.
- Load from device.
- Save to file.
- Load from file.

If in doubt, you can consider an experiment to determine which interface is better. Design multiple interfaces. Randomly assign participants to the A/B groups. Make sure you have enough participants for sufficient statistical power. (This is different from running usability reviews for iterative design.)